# Trace minimization problem with "block diagonal diagonal" constraints?

Tags: matrices, optimization, block-matrices

I've reduced my optimization problem to the following trace minimization problem:
$$\min_X\text{tr}(AXB),$$
subject to that $X$ is a block diagonal matrix whose blocks are all the same -- a diagonal matrix $\Sigma$:
$$
 X=\begin{pmatrix}
  \Sigma & \bf0 & \cdots \\
  \bf0 & \Sigma & \cdots \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Not sure if this helps, but each element of $\Sigma$ is guaranteed $>0$.

How should I impose this constraint on $X$?

P.S.: I'm sure it's stupid to call $X$ "block diagonal diagonal" -- please suggest a better name :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition $A$ and $B$ so that they have conforming block structures to $X$. Let $A_{ij}$ denotes the $(i,j)$-th sub-block and similarly for $B$. Then
$$
\operatorname{tr}(AXB)=\operatorname{tr}\sum_{i,k}(A_{ik}\Sigma B_{ki})=\operatorname{tr}\left(\left(\sum_{i,k}B_{ki}A_{ik}\right)\Sigma\right)=\langle\mathbf c,\mathbf s\rangle,
$$
where $\mathbf c$ is the diagonal of $C=\sum_{i,k}B_{ki}A_{ik}$ and $\mathbf s$ is the diagonal of $\Sigma$. Now,

- $\inf_{\mathbf s>0}\,\langle\mathbf c,\mathbf s\rangle=-\infty$ when $\mathbf c$ has a negative entry,
- $\inf_{\mathbf s>0}\langle\mathbf c,\mathbf s\rangle=0$ when all elements of $\mathbf c$ are nonnegative; unless $\mathbf c$ has a zero entry, this infinum is not attainable.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis! This question might be stupid, but may I ask why in this case we use infimum instead of minimum?

Comment: @SibbsGambling The term "minimum" means something attainable. In your case, since $\mathbf s$ is required to be entrywise positive, if $\mathbf c$ is also entrywise positive, then the dot product between the two vectors approaches zero when $\mathbf s$ tends to zero. So zero is an infinum of the dot product. Yet this infinum is not attainable, because the dot product of two entrywise positive vectors must be positive.